# Trouble on loading multiple partial templates in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, partial-views

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I would like to understand how can I handle the following situation to avoid the istance variable `@photo` overriding on loading the view.

In my view file I have:

```
<div>
  <%=
    render :partial => 'user/photos',
           :locals  => {
             :photo => @photo = 'test_photo1.jpg',
           }
  %>
</div>

<div>
  <%=
    render :partial => 'user/photos',
           :locals  => {
             :photo => @photo = 'test_photo2.jpg',
           }
  %>
</div>
```

If I load the above view I have a strange behavior on outputting. That seams that the `@photo` class is overwritten (by the second rendering statement) when the page loads. Of course if I make only one rendering all works.

**How can I solve the above problem in order to properly pass variables?**

*Note*: I can not change the `@photo` name. That is, it must be the same for both partial templates.

---

I also tryed this version just deleting the `@photo` variable

```
<div>
  <%=
    render :partial => 'user/photos',
           :locals  => {
             :photo => 'test_photo1.jpg',
           }
  %>
</div>

<div>
  <%=
    render :partial => 'user/photos',
           :locals  => {
             :photo => 'test_photo2.jpg',
           }
  %>
</div>
```

but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
  <%=
    render :partial => 'user/photos',
           :locals  => {:photo = 'test_photo2.jpg'}
  %>
</div>
```

Try that, I dont know why you had `:photo => @photo = 'test_photo2.jpg'`

Also see the [Rails guides on partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). They really let you have a good grasp of the basics.

Comment: @Devin M - I need to use the '@photo' variable in the partial template. ':photo' seams don't be accessible in the partial.

Comment: Then use `@photo` instead of `:photo` in the call

Comment: What are you trying to pass in as a local variable?

Comment: @Devin M - I am trying to pass a variable in order to use that in the partial template, but it seams that on loading\rendering the main view the variable is overwritten (by the second rendering statement) so that there is a unwanted behavior.

Comment: It should render one partial after another and use the local var you have passed into it. If you pass in a different local var then you will get that rendered. Basically, You call render once, it renders what you pass into it. You call it again it renders the new thing you pass into it.

Comment: Whats your partial look like?

Comment: @user502052 if you follow how @devim-m describes, your partial will then have a variable 'photo' available, use that, do not use @photo

Comment: @Devin M & @Dhruva Sagar - SOLVED - That was a JavaScript problem in the partial template!